# .NET 3.5 on win server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I'm trying to install .NET 3.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 on an Amazon instance. I tried the dsim command, but I realised I have no `C:\sources`(only have c drive).

As an anwser to TECHIE007: 
Itried this:

```
DISM /Image:C:\test\offline /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:D:\sources\sxs
```

With both C and D drive But I dont have A `C:\source`. I tried changing something in group policy, enabled something.(I think it had to do with WSUS). I tried through the server manager but get this error:

> The source file could not be found. Try installing again

It tells me to "Specify an alternative source way". But I cant do that since I dont have folder sources?

Comment: What is the actual DISM command line you used?  What "other stuff" did you try exactly?  Did you try enabling it via the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You will either install .NET 3.5 in an online mode.  You can do this via Server Manager -> Add Features -> .NET 3.5. You need an internet connection so that .NETFX binaries are downloaded and installed.

or

Install NETFX in an offline mode with the commandline you used (/limitaccess means do not connect to the internet). But for offline mode you need the Windows 2012 R2 DVD which will have the sources folder. Just mount the DVD and point to that folder in the commandline